# Undeclared Name const when using RAW Built-in function GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to use Raw function in GORM as requirements on my personal project

This is my entity

```
type Student struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Address string `json:"address"`
}
```

so I create constant to be called in RAW param

```
const (RetrieveData = `SELECT id, name, address FROM users WHERE id = ?`)
```

And then I build function

```
type mysqlRepository struct {
    GormDb *gorm.DB
}

func(repo *mysqlRepository) RetrieveUserData(id int) (Student, error) {
    data := Student{}
    
    db := db.GormDb.Raw(RetrieveData, 3).Scan(&data)
    return data, db.Error
}
```

Why do I get warning on my function

```
undeclared name: RetrieveData (compile)go-staticcheck
```

Is it because untype string type?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `RetrieveData` is not accessible in `func RetrieveUserData`
Either move it to same package or use `<package_name>.RetrieveData`

Comment: they are on the same package but in different file. 
I create 

**student_sql_query.go** (This file consists of constant queries)
and **student_sql.go**

Answer (score 0):

use method find()

```
err := DB.Raw("[sql]").Find(&data).Error
```

Comment: which means the query is not stored in variable right?

Comment: sorry, I tested your method and it is right. you'd better check the gorm db connction.